# ¿Cómo hacer gráficos usando loop for?

Tags: r, bucle-for

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

`tab_1, tab_2 tab_3, tab_4, tab_5 ... tab_20`

Deseo generar un gráfico de barras en donde ingresen las 20 tablas.

Uso el siguiente código:

```
matri1<-matrix(1:20, nrow = 10)
layout(matri1)

# Aquí realizo el bucle para asignar las tablas.

for (i in 1:20){
   barplot(tab_[i])
}
```

Pero como es obvio, me sale error.

No sé cómo colocar adentro del paréntesis la sintaxis. Para que se generen los 20 gráficos.

**Gracias de antemano**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando tengas un conjunto de objetos similares numerados, es una buena práctica manejar directamente estos desde una lista y no de forma individual. En tu caso en que ya tienes los objetos individuales puedes:

#### 1. Pasarlos a una lista e iterar por los elementos de la misma

```
tabs <- list(tab_1, tab_2, tab_3, ..., tab_20)

for (tab in tabs) {
    barplot(tab)
}
```

#### 2. Obtener el objeto a partir del nombre

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    tab <- get(paste0("tab_", i))
    barplot(tab)
}
```

Aquí construimos el nombre del objeto `paste0("tab_", i)` del que luego obtendremos una copia mediante `get()`, ese es el principal problema, el hecho que estemos generando una nueva copia, te recomiendo que apuntes a la opción 1.

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias. Salió todo perfecto. Excelente.